# Testing flow combine

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to write some tests for my flow (that I know works by testing it manually), but the unit tests won't work.

I have this view model:

```
class TestViewModel(
    customerRepository: CustomerRepository,
): ViewModel() {
    private val phoneNumber = MutableStateFlow(customerRepository.getCustomer().phoneNumber)
    private val email = MutableStateFlow(customerRepository.getCustomer().email)

    val state: StateFlow<TestContactInformationState> = combine(
        phoneNumber,
        email,
    ) { phoneNumber, email ->
        TestContactInformationState(
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber,
            email = email,
        )
    }.stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        TestContactInformationState(
            customerRepository.getCustomer().phoneNumber,
            customerRepository.getCustomer().email,
        ),
    )

    fun setPhoneNumber(newPhoneNumber: PhoneNumber?) {
        this.phoneNumber.value = newPhoneNumber
    }

    fun setEmail(newEmail: Email?) {
        this.email.value = newEmail
    }
}

data class TestContactInformationState(
    val phoneNumber: PhoneNumber?,
    val email: Email?,
)
```

And I have this test:

```
@Test
fun `testing stuff`() = runTest {
    val customer = FakeCustomerRepository.fakeCustomer.copy(
        phoneNumber = "+46701234567".toPhoneNumber(),
        email = "hello@mail.com".toEmail(),
    )

    val stateHolder = TestViewModel(
        customerRepository = FakeCustomerRepository(
            fakeCustomer = customer,
        ),
    )

    stateHolder.setPhoneNumber("+46701234568".toPhoneNumber())
    stateHolder.setEmail("fs@sefs.se".toEmail())

    assertEquals("+46701234568".toPhoneNumber(), stateHolder.state.value.phoneNumber)
}
```

However it fails with this message:

```
Expected:<+46701234568> but was:<+46701234567>
Expected :+46701234568
Actual   :+46701234567
```

I have also tried with adding advanceUntilIdle() but that doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flows need to be observed.

You are checking the value directly in this line

```
stateHolder.state.value.phoneNumber
```

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
stateHolder.state.first()
```

Notice how `first()` is a suspend function, therefore it needs to be called within your `runTest{}` block.
`first()` is fetching the first emission of your flow. There are other options useful in tests, such as `.toList()` to fetch several emissions of a flow.

In production code you wouldn't use any of this, simply observe the flow or collect it.